# How to access variables in onclick function for in-app browsing in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, deep-linking, inappbrowser

I'm making small web app using angular and ionic. I'm implementing in app browsing with the following line of code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_system','location=yes'); return false;">Stuff</a>
```

It works beautifully with a url hard coded in as above, but I'd like to pass in a variable url. I've tried the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open({{url}}, etc

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('url', etc

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('" + {{url}} + "', etc
```

And various other permutations, but I can't seem to get the correct syntax. Any help is much appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<a target="_blank" ng-href="{{url}}" >Stuff</a>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ttayv25f/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This didn't end up working for me, but I posted my solution below.

Comment: @RachelRose did't you check the demo ?

Answer (score 0):

If other people have the same problem:

Instead of doing everything in the html, I ended up making a separate function in the controller.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller='LinkCtrl'>
    <a href="#" ng-click="clickLink(url)"> 
<div>
```

Note that the url shouldn't be in {{}} when passed into a function like this.

**JS:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('LinkCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.clickLink = function(link) {
    window.open(link, '_system', 'location=yes'); 
    return false;
  };

})
```